# App not Installed with not sign app after format my system

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have build an application(not sign app) from my computer system after one app build that computer system android studio corrupted after android studio corrupted i used gost and install again android studio and build new version of same app with same package name but now it is showing error App not installed what i do please help me

Comment: have you tried after clear project ?

Comment: Try deleting the old version from your phone/tablet first.

Comment: But i want to overwrite my previous version with same package name and same apk name but different version

Answer (score 0):

solution 1 :Go Build > Clean Project and then try run again 
solution 2 :test your app in another device

Comment: If you create another app with this version of Android Studio, the app will be installed? Do not you get any error in Android Studio?

Comment: And make sure the previous version of the your application is not installed on this device

Comment: But i want to overwrite my previous version with same package name and same apk name but different version

Comment: Install your app with a higher version than the version installed on the device. Also, Increase your version of your sqlite database if you need to upgrade it.

Comment: I think the install version of your app on your device is higher than current version of your app ..Is not it?